# propagate grape dependencies for multiple classes

Tags: groovy, groovy-grape

I have this class located in file `StreamingPOIWriter.groovy`

```
@Grapes([
    @Grab(group='org.apache.poi', module='poi', version='3.14'),
    @Grab(group='org.apache.poi', module='poi-ooxml', version='3.14'),
    @Grab(group='org.apache.poi', module='poi-ooxml-schemas', version='3.14')
])

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XMLSlideShow
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSlide

class StreamingPOIWriter {

    XMLSlideShow presentation

    def withPresentation() {
        presentation = new XMLSlideShow()
        this
    }

    def write(filename) {
        presentation.write(new FileOutputStream(filename))
    }

    def withSlide() {
        XSLFSlide slide = presentation.createSlide()
        this
    }
}
```

I compiled it using `groovyc`.

But when I decided to create its instance in another file - `script.groovy`

```
new StreamingPOIWriter()
    .withPresentation()
        .withSlide()
            .write("presentation.pptx")
```

When I find to run it using `groovy script.groovy` I get this error

```
Caught: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XMLSlideShow
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XMLSlideShow
        at script.run(script.groovy:2)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XMLSlideShow
        ... 1 more
```

It seems it's unable to find dependencies required by `StreamingPOIWriter`. 
How to propagate them to `script.groovy`?

`StreamingPOIWriter.groovy` and `script.groovy` are in the same folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is not how Grapes were intended. They were intended to, as you probably found out, run single scripts. If you really want to do what you are doing now, add the @Grapes annotation to `script.groovy` also.

Otherwise, if you're building something a bit more complex, I'd recommend using Gradle instead. `gradle init`, and in your case probably `gradle init --type groovy-library` is your friend.

Comment: Well I thought it is script-related. But I assumed that it is possible to use somehow its dependencies...After all it downloads it in `.m2` folder.